# Center text in table via vertical align is not accurate

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm doing a HTML email and due to Outlooks horrible support I'm building all up on tables. The problem I have is, that I cannot vertically center a text within a `th` element. My markup is pretty simple:

```
<table class="table">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="read-more">READ MORE</th>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

with the following CSS:

```
.read-more { 
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #1fb4e6;
   border-bottom: 4px solid #1e9fc8;
   color: #ffffff;
   font-weight: lighter;
   height: 39px;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
   width: 120px;
}
```

but as the provided image shows, it does not vertically center the text properly. It is slightly shifted above:

[PICTURE](http://dev6.mass1.com/screen.png)

I also tried to do it via `line-height` but that doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `border-bottom` you will see in the snippet that it is clearly in the middle. What will inspect element show in your box model? Maybe you are not using a `reset` stylesheet.

And your height is 39px, so one extra pixel should go up or down.

```css
.read-more { 
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #1fb4e6;
   color: #ffffff;
   font-weight: lighter;
   height: 38px;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
   width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="read-more">READ MORE</th>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: please measure the top and bottom value, you will notice that it is not in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

What properties of the `<th>` tag do you want? I think you would probably be better off with just a plain old `<td>` tag (with `width` and `height` specified), which will handle the `vertical-align` automatically (if you want `vertical-align: middle`).

```
<style>
  td {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

---

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Here is some vertically aligned text inside a <code>&lt;td&gt;</code> tag.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

See [here](http://www.codecademy.com/gilbertVirgo/codebits/sxoY3G/edit).